# A further question about lambda, what does "k" mean here?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

Would anyone please tell me what is k here?

```
def rule(x, y):
    if x == 'high' and y > 10:
         return 1
    else:
         return 0
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'c1':[ 'high' ,'high', 'low', 'low'], 'c2': [0, 23, 17, 4]})
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda k: rule(k['c1'], k['c2']), axis =  1)
df.head()
```

and why can't I just use the following?

```
df['new'] = df["c1","c2"].apply(rule['c1'], ['c2'])
```

Comment: `k` is the row of data.

Comment: thank you, so for a syntax like this: df2 = df.apply(lambda x : x + 10) , does x means the row too?

Comment: It is row only if `axis = 1` is added. Otherwise function is applied to columns, default is `axis = 0`.

Comment: Yes. And please note what @ipj says above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sides that one should understand here.

### Argument for `func` in `obj.apply(func)`

It depends. You can control what is passed as an argument to `func`:

1. If the `obj` is a pandas.DataFrame, as it is if you use apply on `df[["c1", "c2"]]` or just `df`, then refer to [documentation of pd.DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Note that there is also argument `axis` with which you may control if the function is applied to rows (1) or columns (0, Default). Then, there is argument `raw` that can be used to define if the argument passed to `func` will be pd.Series (False, Default) or numpy arrays (True).

   Therefore, by default, columns are passed to `func` (as.pd.Series). Now, since you have `axis=1`, the data is passed row by row, as pd.Series. That means, type of `k` would be pd.Series and it would contain data for one row.
2. If the `obj` is pandas.Series as it is if you use `df["col"]`, then refer to [documentation of pandas.Series.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html). As you can see, in this case pandas will either feed each element in the Series to the function (if func processes one value at time) or the whole array (if `func` is numpy ufunc).

### lambdas are just functions

The `k` in the lambda is just a name for the argument. See, for example

```py
myfunc = lambda k: rule(k['c1'], k['c2'])
```

is roughly equivalent to

```py
def myfunc(k):
    return rule(k['c1'], k['c2'])
```

### Why can't I just apply following?

In the following line

```py
df['new'] = df["c1","c2"].apply(rule['c1'], ['c2'])
```

The argument(s) passed to `apply` would not be callable, and that is the reason this would not work. Since `rule` is a function, `rule['c1']` makes no sense. There is no attribute 'c1' for that function.

---

In case you just want to know *how this should be done*, I would recommend using `np.vectorize` as in the @ipj's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is possible to vectorize arbitrary function:

```
import numpy as np
df['new'] = np.vectorize(rule)(df.c1, df.c2)
```

Above solution is not changing Your original function.

Another way is to rewrite function:

```
def rule(row):
    if row['c1'] == 'high' and row['c2'] > 10:
         return 1
    else:
         return 0
```

and apply it to dataframe:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(rule, axis = 1)
```

Note that `axis = 1` is necessary to pass arguments by rows to function applied.

Comment: Thank you! allow me to ask: 
if row['c1'] == 'high' and row['c2'] > 10, is "row" a reserved word? and when to use it? this is my first time seeing it.

Comment: No it's not reserved, it may be any name for example `x`. But I named it row to indicate what is processed here :-)